# Possible to mine on nvidia Pascal (10xx) GPUs?

Tags: gpu-mining

I haven't found a miner that works yet on 1070s. Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, could you share how you've done it?

Comment: Can you give more details on what you have tried?

Answer (score 6):

My EVGA 1070 Founders Edition maxes at 470 h/s with Tsiv's CCMiner pool software, though its possible I'm missing some settings that could help it hash higher. Pretty stinky scores. This is worse than many older cards. Basically, there is not yet good public mining software for the newer cards.

Source code found here: https://github.com/tsiv/ccminer-cryptonight/
Compiled Windows binaries are under "releases".

Instructions for compiling on Ubuntu 16.04 here: https://steemit.com/monero/@mobidick/how-to-mine-monero-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-ccminer-cryptonight

Comment: Newer version here, supports mining against the daemon https://github.com/hyc/ccminer-cryptonight

Comment: Hi, any ideas if there is a 64 bit version of this? I have ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit) and it seems it doesn't build there for me. I get "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables" and this looks like a 32 bit problem, not sure thou...

Comment: I don't ever build from source. I just use the precompiled binaries.

Answer (score 5):

My GTX 1080 is maxing out at around 537 H/s. This is also using tsiv's ccminer, which XMR_Eric linked in his answer. I've found the best settings for the card to be 80 blocks of 12 threads. Default settings yield around 200 H/s I think. You can set 12x80 by appending --launch=12x80 to the end of the command when running it.